# Piecewise function, which follows equation but ends in nothing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recreational-mathematics, piecewise-continuity

I was wondering if there is a way to create a function that follows a regular equation (for example y = 1 + x) when $x$ is smaller than 3, but ends in nothing or null when $x$ becomes larger than 3.

The equation thus simply just stops.

What would I put down in the piecewise function: $null$, $ε$ (empty string), $NaN$ ..? What is a good mathematical way of writing down this function?

As an example of what it could be:

$y=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}null & x> 3\\1+x & x\le 3\end{array}\right.$

[Screenshot of graph for example equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn5gs.png)

Thanks, Mudi

Comment: well you can just define this function's domain to be within this range, so something like $$f(x):(-\infty,3]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: As pointed out, this is why we have the concept of *domain*.

Comment: But there is not a way of stating a variable that represents 'nothing' inside the piecewise function?

Comment: @Mudimans "Undefined" rather than "null" is probably better.

Comment: I could write down 0/0, in that case

Comment: writing 0/0 is not the way. A definition in mathematics should have each thing mentioned in it defined.

Comment: Writing something like "null if $x >3$" would be seen as odd and unprofessional.  You would simply define your function to have domain $(-\infty, 3]$ and everyone would know what you meant.

Comment: The domain and range were what I was looking for! Is it also possible for a polar equation, to specify the range and domain for the x and y values?